# Is it possible for StreamWriter to open different files?

Tags: c#, file, stream

I has initialized the `StreamWriter` instance and associated it with "MyFile.txt"

```
System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("MyFile.txt");
```

So now I can write data into this file

```
sw.Write("Hello, world!");
```

Is it possible to open **another** file with **the same** `StreamWriter` (sw) instance some way like:

```
sw.Reopen("MySecondFile");
```

Or not/it's senseless?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with reusing the same streamwriter instance?

Comment: @knittl I worked with c++'s `ifstream` and `ofstream` for many times before. So possibility to reopen streams with the same instance is seems to be obvious for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation on StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.StreamWriter.aspx). The only way to associate the `StreamWriter` with a file is in the constructor.

So, no, it's not possible to re-use an instance with a second file

Answer (score 0):

Using `StreamWriter` you need to create a new instance to write to another file.

Answer (score -1):

Simply create a new StreamWriter instance:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("MyFile.txt");
sw.Write("Hello world!");
sw.Close();
sw = new StreamWriter("SecondFile");
sw.Write("Goodbye world!");
```

So, in a way it's senseless, since you can create new instances cheaply. The old instance will eventually get garbage collected automatically, so you don't have to worry about memory leaks.

Comment: OP knows how to do it with new instance. `Is it possible to open another file with the same StreamWriter (sw) instance some way l`

Comment: But where's the effective difference? What is the problem he is trying to solve? Part of the question was also "is it senseless?".

Comment: Didn't noticed `is it senseless` thing... revoking my downvote. Ohh hell my vote is locked..!!

Comment: @BhushanFirake Maybe there's no effective difference at all. But I worked with c++'s `ifstream` and `ofstream` for many times. So possibility to reopen streams with the same instance is seems to be obvious for me.

Comment: @BhushanFirake: I edited my question to give a little bit more explanation as to why re-opening is senseless.